# Summing from one column based on data from multiple others

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to sum all the rows from one column based on if the truth values to the input I am checking on other columns is true.

This works in a simple case based on two parameters; but if I want to check for two conditions, I cannot use .loc, and I have no clue how to do comparisons otherwise.

What I am trying to do:

```
findMe = df.loc[df["Column1"] == "data1" and df["column2"] == "data2], then, 
column1.sum()
```

How might I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering and `loc` for select column:

```
df.loc[(df["Column1"] == "data1") & (df["Column2"] == "data2"), 'Column1'].sum()
```

Or use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) for filtering:

```
df.query("Column1 == 'data1' & Column2 == 'data2'")['Column1'].sum()
```

But `data1` has to be numeric, else strings values are concatenated:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[1,3,3],
                   'Column2':['data1','data2', 'data2']})
print (df)
   Column1 Column2
0        1   data1
1        3   data2
2        3   

print (df.loc[(df["Column1"] == 3) & (df["Column2"] == "data2"), 'Column1'])
1    3
2    3
Name: Column1, dtype: int64

a = df.loc[(df["Column1"] == 3) & (df["Column2"] == "data2"), 'Column1'].sum()
print (a)
6
b = df.query("Column1 == 3 & Column2 == 'data2'")['Column1'].sum()
print (b)
6
```

In this sample is posssible sum `True`s in mask and multiple by finding value `3`:

```
a = ((df["Column1"] == 3) & (df["Column2"] == "data2")).sum() * 3
print (a)
6
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':['data2','data1', 'data1'],
                   'Column2':['data1','data2', 'data2']})
print (df)
  Column1 Column2
0   data2   data1
1   data1   data2
2   data1   data2

c = df.loc[(df["Column1"] == "data1") & (df["Column2"] == "data2"), 'Column1'].sum()
print (c)
data1data1
```

Comment: How might I do the same types of comparisons if data1 is a string?

Comment: I add sample for better explanation.